# Response header access from ng-resource head request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a head request via a ngResource as follows

```
let resource = $resource(url, null, {
    head: {
       method: 'HEAD',
       transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
          console.log(headers('X-my-header');
          return data;
       }
    }
}
resource.$head();
```

It is making the proper head request, which I can witness in the network tab; however, I have no access to the HTTP headers. If I use $http, I can access these headers. I was wondering, if anyone knows a good way to access the RESPONSE HEADERS ('X-my-header') from a ngResource HEAD request?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update transformResponse function like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('myResource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/', {}, {
    head: {
       method: 'HEAD',
       transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
        var response = {};
        response.data = data;
        response.headers = headers();
        response.myCustomValue = headers('X-my-header');
        return response;
       }
    }
  });
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myResource) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  myResource.head(function successFoo() {

  }, function errorFoo(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pZiS9QGIhG9BSV9bG14F?p=preview)

Comment: When I adapt your changes AND print out data, all I get is something like the following: {$resolved: true}

Comment: That means you did something wrong. I update my answer and add plunkr.